Bash process substitution only sometimes works?
(1) Why does this error when executed, but not when sourced?
(2) Is there a way to resolve this, to make it work when executed?
> echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash
> help | head -n 1
> fd=<(echo "this is foobar.")
> cat <$fd' > foobar
> chmod u+x foobar
> . foobar
GNU bash, version 5.2.37(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin23.4.0)
this is foobar.
> ./foobar
GNU bash, version 5.2.37(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin23.4.0)
./foobar: line 4: 0: Bad file descriptor
> 


I don't know why it's different when sourced, but I suspect the problem is that the pipe for the process substitution is closed at the end of the assignment statement, so you can't use it on the next line.

I'm getting a different error in bash 4.4.23(1): ./foobar: line 4: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory.

You can reproduce it in the source case by running an external command before cat <$fd, e.g. /bin/echo foo. I think there's some kind of timing issue involving how quickly the subprocess exits.

@choroba I think they're essentially the same, it depends on precisely how /dev/fd is implemented. On MacOS, accessing a nonexistent FD causes the "Bad file descriptor" error.

In general, I don't think there's any expectation that the filename that process substitution expands to can be used after that command line.

Are you using set -x to see what is actually being executed? Good luck.

@Barmar, yes, I was just wondering if anyone knew why there was a difference in the two contexts.

@shellter, I haven't used set -x before... interesting. But it output the same thing in both cases, except the last line was either the error or the 'this is foobar' output line.

yes, the set -x won't "propagate" to when you source the file with . foobar, you can add it to your script that you are redirecting by either using  echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash -x > help ... or inserting it as the 2nd line of that redirected script. You'll then see the "actual" line that is being executed preceded with +.
